# Am i allowed to sell a Blender project including the Blender installer?

Tags: blend-files

Am i allowed to sell a download of a project for e.g. 2.00$?
And may i include the Blender installer in there?
Am i also allowed to include free blender addons in the download folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.blender.org/about/license/

"Free to sell **your** work" seems very clear. It doesn't include Blender and it also doesn't include addons, as long as they don't use different Licensing Models.

You may distribute blender with your work as a dependency, but you obviously may not declare it as your work.